# An integral ascribable to generalized Gaussian form

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, gaussian-integral

In [this paper](http://users.physics.harvard.edu/~schwartz/15cFiles/Lecture11-WavePackets.pdf) (page 7), the following integral is to be solved:

$$A(x,t) = \frac{\sigma_x}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i kx} e^{- i \left[ k_c v_p + (k - k_c)v_g + \frac{1}{2}(k - k_c)^2 \Gamma \right] t} e^{- \frac{\sigma_x^2}{2}(k - k_c)^2} e^{i x_0 (k - k_c)} dk$$

where $i$ is the imaginary unit and $\sigma_x, k_c, v_p, v_g, \Gamma, x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ are constants; $x, k, t \in \mathbb{R}$ are variables.

The solution should be

$$A(x,t) = \exp \left[ \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{x - (x_0 + v_gt)}{\sqrt{\sigma_x^2 - i \Gamma t}} \right)^2 \right] e^{i k_c x} e^{- ik_c t(v_g - v_p)}$$

But my result is different. From the initial integral, I get

$$A(x,t) = \frac{\sigma_x}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-i k_c v_p t} e^{i k_c v_g t} e^{-i x_0 k_c} e^{i \left[ kx - \left( k v_g + \frac{1}{2}(k - k_c)^2 \Gamma \right) \right] t} e^{- \frac{\sigma_x^2}{2}(k - k_c)^2} e^{i x_0 k} dk =$$

$$ = \frac{\sigma_x}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} e^{-i k_c v_p t} e^{i k_c v_g t} e^{-i x_0 k_c} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i (x - v_g t + x_0) k} e^{- (k - k_c)^2 \left( i \frac{1}{2} \Gamma t + \frac{\sigma_x^2}{2} \right)} dk$$

The integral is in the [Gaussian generalized form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#Generalizations)

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\beta (x - \alpha)^2} e^{\gamma x} dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta}} e^{\frac{\gamma^2}{4\beta} + \alpha \gamma}$$

So,

$$A(x,t) = \frac{\sigma_x}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} e^{-i k_c v_p t} e^{i k_c v_g t} e^{-i x_0 k_c} \left[ \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{i \frac{1}{2} \Gamma t + \frac{\sigma_x^2}{2}}} e^{- \frac{(x - v_g t + x_0)^2}{2i \Gamma t + 2 \sigma_x^2}} e^{i k_c (x - v_g t + x_0)} \right]$$

This is far from being the expected result, where the square root doesn't even exist.

- Did I make some (algebraic) mistake?
- Is there a way (maybe transforming the square root in complex exponential?) to arrange my solution to fit to the provided solution above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in the integral as is written as $kx$ should not be multiplied by time $t$. This is a straightforward computation of quantum mechanics. So, I rewrite the integral as (I have also changed $x_0\rightarrow -x_0$)
$$
A(x,t) = \frac{\sigma_x}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i kx - i\left[  k_c v_p + (k - k_c)v_g + \frac{1}{2}(k - k_c)^2 \Gamma \right] t} e^{- \frac{\sigma_x^2}{2}(k - k_c)^2} e^{-i x_0 (k - k_c)} dk.
$$
It is useful at this stage to introduce a new integration variable $\tilde k=k-k_c$. Then one has
$$
A(x,t) = \frac{\sigma_x}{2 \sqrt{\pi}}e^{ik_cx}e^{-ik_cv_pt} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i{\tilde k}x - i\left[ {\tilde k}v_g + \frac{1}{2}{\tilde k}^2 \Gamma \right] t} e^{- \frac{\sigma_x^2}{2}{\tilde k}^2} e^{-i{\tilde k} x_0} d{\tilde k}.
$$
This is
$$
A(x,t) = \frac{\sigma_x}{2 \sqrt{\pi}}e^{ik_cx}e^{-ik_cv_pt} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left[\sigma_x^2+i\Gamma t\right]{\tilde k}^2}
e^{i{\tilde k}(x-x_0-v_gt)}d{\tilde k}.
$$
This integral can be evaluated using the formula
$$
   \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{\alpha}{2}x^2+\beta x}dx=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}}e^{\frac{\beta^2}{2\alpha}}
$$
that yields the final result
$$
   A(x,t)=\frac{\sigma_x}{2 \sqrt{\pi}}e^{ik_cx}e^{-ik_cv_pt}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\sigma_x^2+i\Gamma t}}e^{-\frac{(x-x_0-v_gt)^2}{2\left(\sigma_x^2+i\Gamma t\right)}}.
$$

I guess that the author of the lecture is mostly interested in the spreading of the wave-packet in time rather than to obtain the exact formula with all the constants right in place.

Comment: Above all, thank you, also for the corrections. A couple of clarifications are needed:
1) is there any particular reason why you made the variable change $x_0 \rightarrow -x_0$?
2) In the third formula, between the square brackets I think there should be the quantity $\sigma_x^2 + i \Gamma t$ and **not** $\sigma_x^2 - i \Gamma t$. This would also change the final result.
Moreover, the Gaussian integral formula should have $e^{\frac{\beta^2}{2 \alpha}}$ instead of $e^{- \frac{\beta^2}{2 \alpha}}$. I agree with you about the author, but an exact computation should be possible.

Comment: And with the last integral I can't get the result in the linked document, the result that I get is only slightly different from the one I obtained in the question.

Comment: I get $\sigma_x^2-i\Gamma t$ because of the minus sign in the exponential. The change of sign in $x_0$ grants the coincidence with the lectures' result otherwise this is just another misprint by the author. The problem is in the lectures and not in the way the integral is computed. The author's aim was just to show the spreading of the wave-packet without too much care about mathematical details. Aside form this, the results coincide. The changes you see are my efforts to comply with the aims of the author respecting mathematics.

Comment: Sorry, how can you obtain $e^{- \frac{1}{2} {\tilde k}^2 (\sigma_x^2 - i \Gamma t)}$ from $e^{- i \frac{1}{2}{\tilde k}^2 \Gamma t} e^{- \frac{\sigma_x^2}{2}{\tilde k}^2}$?

Comment: Ah thanks. I fixed it.

Comment: You gave a big help. Anyway, just to let you know, the result I get from your last integral is not the one given in the document. In fact, I get

$$A(x,t)=\frac{\sigma_x}{2 \sqrt{\pi}}e^{i k_c x_0}e^{-ik_cv_pt}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\sigma_x^2+i\Gamma t}}e^{-\frac{(x-x_0-v_gt)^2}{2\left(\sigma_x^2+i\Gamma t\right)}}$$

Comment: I agree, the lecturer was somewhat sloppy about this integral as you have seen. I think he was too much aimed at the physical content and overlooked the mathematical one.

Comment: If you would change $\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{\alpha}} e^{-\frac{\beta^2}{2\alpha}}$ with $\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{\alpha}} e^{\frac{\beta^2}{2\alpha}}$ and delete the last integral (which, as we were saying, does not carry to the result in the document), I would choose your answer! Or, if you prefer, I can edit it.

Comment: Did it. Thanks.